# Run a Qgis Standalone Application using Qgis stored at a Network

Tags: python, batch-file, networking, qgis

I have written a standalone application (in python) for QGis which should be used in my Company. The problem is, that it isn't useful if everyone has to Download Qgis etc. to make it run. 
So my idea was, to put Qgis on the network, because the application is only using some libraries. 
I start the program with a batch file, with the directories connected to the network and I get exception saying that DLL load failed and is talking about the qgis.core library.

The Error of the Command Promt:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
file "Y.\OSGeo4W64\CodesNetrtest\ExistingCCsrun.py", line 2 in (module)
from qgis.core import *
File "Y:\O52RC~F\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 36, in (module)
from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeomtetry
File "Y:\O52RC~F\apps\qgis\python\qgis\core\__init__.py", line3, in (module)

from qgis._core import *

Import Error: DLL load failed: The declared modul has not been found.
```

The batch file I use looks like:

```
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=Z:\OSGeo4W64
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\env.bat
@echo off
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib

set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis
set PATH=Z:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;Z:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74;%PATH%
cd %HOMEPATH%\development
start "Python IDE aware of Quantum GIS" /B "Z:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python.exe" %*

"Z:\Users\Christian\Documents\Wirtschaftsingenieurwesen\SS15\Bachelorarbeit KNORR\PotentialanalyseCCS\Codes\ExistingCCSrun.py"
```

Could someone help me by saying what am I doing wrong, an if there even is a possibility to realise my idea? Unfortunately I'm not a expert concerning those subjects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I've changed order in the PATH and PYTHONPATH environment variables.

```
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=Z:\OSGeo4W64
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\env.bat
@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%;
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib;%PATH%;

set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%PYTHONPATH%;
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages;%PYTHONPATH%;
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis
set PATH=Z:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;Z:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74;%PATH%
cd %HOMEPATH%\development
start "Python IDE aware of Quantum GIS" /B "Z:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python.exe" %*

"Z:\Users\Christian\Documents\Wirtschaftsingenieurwesen\SS15\Bachelorarbeit KNORR\PotentialanalyseCCS\Codes\ExistingCCSrun.py"
```